# Setting default field type based on wildcard

Tags: elasticsearch

I have many fields within my index where the field name ends in _count (e.g. `page_count`, `order_count` etc.) and I always want these to be `long`. I tried to create what I thought was a default mapping as follows:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "_all": {
        "enabled": false,
        "norms": {
          "enabled": false
        }
      },
      "properties": {
        "*_count": {
          "type": "long"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "index.query.default_field": "message",
    "number_of_replicas": 2,
    "number_of_shards": 3
  },
  "template": "core-app-*"
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work as I now have string fields in my most recent index:

```
"page_count":{  
  "type":"text",
  "fields":{  
     "keyword":{  
        "type":"keyword",
        "ignore_above":256
     }
  }
}
```

Is this the right way to create a mapping based on a wildcard? I'm assuming not because it doesn't seem to work... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by using `dynamic templates` feature in elasticsearch.

```
PUT _template/core-app-template
{
  "template": "core-app-*",
  "settings": {
    "index.query.default_field": "message",
    "number_of_replicas": 2,
    "number_of_shards": 3
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "_all": {
        "enabled": false,
      "norms": {
        "enabled": false
      }
    }
    },
    "my_type": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "_count_as_long": {
            "match_mapping_type": "*",
            "match": "*_count",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "long"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Note:** watch out `index_type` in above example I took liberty to define it as `my_type` so when you are creating this `index template` use your actual `index_type` in place of `my_type`